# I want to filter a table using the information of another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have large dataset with information (It has more columns than shown below, which are unnecessary for this). I have generated a sample dataset like below, we can call it table_1:

| ID | CostCenter | Project | Scope |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_100 | CD103 | Zeus |  |
| ID_101 | CD103 | Hades |  |
| ID_102 | CD103 | Zeus |  |
| ID_102 | CD103 | Hades |  |
| ID_103 | CD105 | Hades |  |
| ID_103 | CD105 | Zeus |  |
| ID_103 | CD105 | Afrodita |  |
| ID_104 | CD105 | Afrodita |  |
| ID_104 | CC102 | Zeus |  |
| ID_105 | CC104 | Afrodita |  |
| ID_106 | CC102 | Afrodita |  |
| ID_107 | CC102 | Zeus |  |

Also, I want the user to have freedom to freely define rules of exclusion. I have created a table (which for them is an excel i can automatically upload to the database) to define this exclusions (we can call it exclusions_table:

| exclusion_column | Value | Scope |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CostCenter | CC_104 | Out |
| ID | ID_107 | Out |
| Project | Zeus | Out |

The point is I would use the information of the second column to populate the first column. The user can freely say, in the ID project, I want that all ID_107 have a Scope "Out". Or that all project zeus are out. So they put the name of the column they want out, and the value of the column they want out (project - Zeus, Id - ID_107). The output is the first column but with the Scope Out when it should be out defined by the users (second table). Output:

| ID | CostCenter | Project | Scope |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_100 | CD103 | Zeus | Out |
| ID_101 | CD103 | Hades |  |
| ID_102 | CD103 | Zeus | Out |
| ID_102 | CD103 | Hades |  |
| ID_103 | CD105 | Hades |  |
| ID_103 | CD105 | Zeus | Out |
| ID_103 | CD105 | Afrodita |  |
| ID_104 | CD105 | Afrodita |  |
| ID_104 | CC102 | Zeus | Out |
| ID_105 | CC104 | Afrodita | Out |
| ID_106 | CC102 | Afrodita |  |
| ID_107 | CC102 | Zeus | Out |

**Worth mention that the number of columns of the first table is mutable, it can change**. How would you do this? I can't find a solution in SQL

I am fairly new to SQL world. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks you very much for your time. See you!

Comment: The question is bit unclear what you want as output, but it would be easier if you created the exclusions_table as copy of the table_1 with columns that you need. Then populate the columns you want to be included in the query. That way you can use regular joins instead of dynamic SQL that your current setup requires.

Comment: Myabe it's better explained now, but I understand your idea.